# how to see pdf files in firefox window without disabling IDM

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

When I triy to open any pdf files in firefox browser internet download manager captures its link and shows the prompt screen to download that file.

I want to open that pdf file in the browser itself without disabling IDM. Is there any shortcut key to do this?

Comment: Foxit Reader Plug-In For Firefox and Netscape - works for me. For a better answer you´d need to specify which reader you use. I think it may install during the Foxit installation rather than as a separate etension.

Comment: i am using adobe reader plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Open up IDM, click **`Options`**

[image]

2.In **`General`** tab of IDM's configuration window, click **`Keys`** button:

[image]

3.Check the check-box *Prevent downloading with IDM* ,choose any key combination you want.**(YOU HAVE TO PRESS AND HOLD THESE KEYS WHILE OPENING A PDF LINK IN FIREFOX)**

[image]

**Another way:**
In `File types` tab, just delete the **PDF** extension, the below picture shown means IDM will capture the PDF files, to read it in Browser, just delete PDF and click OK. ***You may have to restart Firefox*** 
[image]

Comment: i am new in superuser ..and my reputation is not above 15 .. i will upvote your answer as soon as my reputation exceeds 15............

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> (don't remove your finger from any of the keys) and then click on PDF file link, it will open your PDF in a separate tab.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to click <kbd>Alt</kbd> button.
If you want to temporary disable IDM for single download you may hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> button while clicking on the download link to prevent IDM from taking the download.